# React native text input stops scrolling on android after reaching message box max height

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Im having an issue with TextInput in react native where once you go past the max height when writing a message its stops auto scrolling and this doesn't seem to be an issue of ios. Here's my code for the textinput:

```
<TextInput
                underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                ref = {'messageBox'}
                style = {[
                    styles.messageBoxEntry,
                    this.state.archived && styles.messageBoxEntryArchived,
                    {height: Math.min(Math.max(this.state.messageBoxHeight, 35), this.state.messageBoxLimit)},
                    {marginLeft: 10}
                ]}
                multiline = {!this.state.archived}
                editable = {!this.state.archived}
                onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
                    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                     let height = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height
                     this.setState({messageBoxHeight: height, scrollChat: true})
                    }
                 }}
                 onChange = {(event) =>{
                    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                        let height = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height + 5
                        this.setState({messageBoxHeight: height, scrollChat: true})
                    }
                 }}
                placeholder = {
                    this.state.archived?
                        str_chat.messageBoxPlaceholderArchived :
                        str_chat.messageBoxPlaceholder
                }
                selectionColor={appColors.appGoldTint}
                autoCorrect={true}
                onChangeText={(messageText) => this.setState({messageText})}
                />
```

Comment: How come you have the same code in onChange for Android?  shouldn't you just run that code for both platforms in onContentSizeChange?

Comment: no there is a issue where onContentSizeChange only triggers once for android but I think it may be fixed in more recent versions of react native